# Volatile Loading Times

Tags: python, pandas, window

I am loading large files into memory using Python.

```
df = pd.read_hdf( filename, 'data' )
```

Sometimes it takes about a minute. Sometimes it takes a few seconds. It seems to take a few seconds if I run it twice in a row, or if I am sequentially going through all the files in a directory.

I suspect this might be something to do with the way the hard drive works and caching. Is there a way to make this less eratic?

Comment: _" It seems to take a few seconds if I run it twice in a row"_ The file content is probably cached by the OS in RAM.

Comment: I don't think it is cached in RAM. Because if I sequentially load lots of files that are more than my system's total RAM, then I still get the same result.

Comment: I didn't noticed you were using HDF. I don't know well this technology. Sorry. But, maybe something like the _metadata_ being cached ?